# .jar file not running without resource folder

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, buildpath

I followed a tutorial on YouTube on how to build a game in Java. I changed the code quiet a bit but kept all the basics. When I export my game with eclipse as a runnable jar the game only works when the resources folder is in the same directory as the jar. Otherwise I just get a blank screen even though the resource folder is in the build path and in the jar.

You can look at the full code here:  https://github.com/CodeNMore/New-Beginner-Java-Game-Programming-Src/tree/master/Episode%2034/TileGame

But I think the most important parts are these:

```
public class FontLoader {

public static Font loadFont(String path, float size){
    try {
        return Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(path)).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, size);
    } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return null;
}
}

public class Utils {

public static String loadFileAsString(String path){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            builder.append(line + "\n");

        br.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return builder.toString();
}

public static int parseInt(String number){
    try{
        return Integer.parseInt(number);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
    }

}

public class ImageLoader {

public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path){
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

I didn't alter these in my version.

My next guess would be that the Manifest file is the issue but I honestly don't know how I would have to alter it for the jar to run properly. 
The automatically created one just contains this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: main.Launcher
```

Comment: To make it work even if the font is included in the JAR you have to use [`Font.createFont(int, InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#createFont(int,java.io.InputStream)) (instead of [`Font.createFont(int, File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#createFont(int,java.io.File)) as files do not work with files inside a JAR) and get the `InputStream` the same way as you did in `loadImage`.

Comment: Things in a jar are **not** files and you can't use file APIs to read them.

Comment: @howlger Thank you I fixed the Code for the FontLoader. Just a quick question is that the same reason why the loadFileAsString Method doesn't work?

Comment: @bry42 Yes, instead of `new FileReader(path)` you need e.g. an `InputStreamReader`.